# rawtx & rawblock ZMQ at the same time?

Tags: zeromq

I need your opinion, do you mind ? :)

I'm bulding a javascript layer on top of bitcoind.
I have bitcoind running on my server with rpc & zmq enabled.

```
daemon=1
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=xxxxxxxx
rpcpassword=xxxxxxxxx
server=1
rest=1
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://*:28332
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://*:28332
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://*:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://*:28332
rpcworkqueue=100
```

My program goal is to listen for `rawblock` and `rawtx` ZMQ channels. This is my zmq client:

```
const socket = ZMQ.socket('sub')
socket.connect('tcp://myserverip:28332')

socket.on('message', (channel, data) => { 
  console.log(channel.toString())
})
```

#### So here is what happens :

subscribing to `rawtx` **alone** works, I receive the tx flow (approx 2.5tx per second)

```
socket.subscribe('rawtx')
```

subscribing to `rawblock` **alone** also works, I receive blocks (approx 1block per 10minutes)

```
socket.subscribe('rawblock')
```

But here is my problem, when subscribing to **both**, i do receive `rawtx` but no `rawblock` !

```
socket.subscribe('rawblock')
socket.subscribe('rawtx')
```

I'm assuming the ZMQ socket is flooded with `rawtx`, which result in missing `rawblock` event.

My question is: how would you debug this ? Have you guys faced this situation already ?

I know I could use the `blocknotify` option in bitcoind to forward the `blockhash` back to my client, and then load the rawblock via an `rpc` call back to bitcoind, but then I would use 2 different mechanisms (one for `rawtx` and blocknotify for `rawblock`) for something that was supposed to work in the first place :)

Thanks for your feedback !!

Comment: Are you sure that `socket.subscribe` allows you to subscript to multiple things in the way that you have done it? It seems like it could only be subscribing to the latest thing that `subscribe` was called on, and that would be `rawtx`. What happens if you reverse the order?

Comment: order does not matter I've checked. and if I sub to `rawtx` & `hashtx` i receive both. I just don't receive `rawblock` when used with `rawtx` at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Try to subscribe by using prefix **raw** as topic . After this you will get both message on the one listener.

```
socket.subscribe('raw');

socket.on('message', (topicRaw: Buffer, bodyRaw: Buffer, ...tailRaw: Buffer[]) => {

    const sequenceRaw = tailRaw[tailRaw.length - 1];
    const sequence = sequenceRaw.readInt32LE(0);
    const topic = topicRaw.toString();


    if (topic == 'rawtx') {
        const rawTX = bodyRaw.toString('hex');
        console.log(topic, sequence, rawTX);

    } else if (topic == 'rawblock') {

        const rawBlock = bodyRaw.toString('hex', 0, 80);
        console.log(topic, sequence, rawBlock);
    }
});
```